# How to find single row data from joined table in mysql?

Tags: mysql

```
Product

id | name       | description
1  | one        | test        
2  | two        | test
```

Joined Table

```
id | product_id | is_profile | image 
1  | 1          | 0          | 1.jpg   
2  | 1          | 0          | 2.jpg  
3  | 2          | 0          | 3.jpg  
4  | 2          | 1          | 4.jpg
```

How to find a single image field from joined table if is_profile!=1 then any data else is_profile=1 particular data with is_profile=1? 
I am using join query with product table.
query:

```
SELECT Product.*,
  (SELECT joined_table.image
   FROM joined_table
   WHERE joined_table.product_id=Product.id
     AND joined_table.is_profile=IF(joined_table.is_profile = '1', 1, 0) LIMIT 1) product_image
FROM products AS Product
```

Comment: where is is_profile column ?

Comment: I have made it readable..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check

```
select p.id, p.name, p.description,(select case when
(select jt.image from joined_table jt where 
 jt.product_id=p.id and jt.is_profile=1 limit 1)
is not null
then (select jt.image from joined_table jt where 
 jt.product_id=p.id and jt.is_profile=1 limit 1)
else (select jt.image from joined_table jt where 
 jt.product_id=p.id and jt.is_profile=0 limit 1)
end) as img
from Product p where p.id=2 limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 select Product.*,COALESCE((select joined_table.image from joined_table  where  joined_table.product_id=Product.id  and     joined_table.is_profile=1 limit 1), (select joined_table.image from product_picker_images  where    joined_table.product_id=Product.id  and     joined_table.is_profile=0 limit 1)) product_image from products as Product
```

I did it in this pattern